# Spin lock with std::atomic_flag - put the thread to sleep or not?

Tags: c++, multithreading, c++11, thread-safety, std

From [cppreference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/atomic/atomic_flag)

```
#include <thread>
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>
#include <atomic>
 
std::atomic_flag lock = ATOMIC_FLAG_INIT;
 
void f(int n)
{
    for (int cnt = 0; cnt < 100; ++cnt) {
        while (lock.test_and_set(std::memory_order_acquire))  // acquire lock
             ; // spin  <===================== no sleep
        std::cout << "Output from thread " << n << '\n';
        lock.clear(std::memory_order_release);               // release lock
    }
}
 
int main()
{
    std::vector<std::thread> v;
    for (int n = 0; n < 10; ++n) {
        v.emplace_back(f, n);
    }
    for (auto& t : v) {
        t.join();
    }
}
```

Is there a reasoning behind not writing in the spin-lock while loop `std::this_thread::sleep_for`? Normally when I write spin locks I always send the thread to sleep not to make processor run the thread all the time in the loop for nothing. Am I doing it wrong?

Comment: It's a judgement call.  Spinning is usually because you don't want the overhead of a something like a mutex (kernel call, scheduler).   Spinning and yielding is somewhere between the two.

Comment: @RichardCritten and std::this_thread::sleep_for will leap to a kernel call?

Comment: It has to. Yielding is a operating system scheduler function - put thread to sleep preserving its state and add the thread to the list of threads to be scheduled in the future.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A [spinlock](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spinlock) is when a thread is *not* put to sleep, but instead running (looping) until a certain condition is met. It does not involve a trip to the kernel (unless you're already inside the kernel).

Using `this_thread::sleep_for` would defeat the purpose, i.e. the thread would be put to sleep by the **kernel**, and re-scheduled for execution by the **kernel** later on. Such a solution is not a spinlock anymore.